# Xcode using object in xib to pass button events

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, events

I tried to pass the button clicked event from one view controller to another, here's what I've done:

1. Create a view controller called FirstViewController(also create a xib file) and put a button on it;
2. create SecondViewController(without a xib file), and added a IBAction method like:

   `- (IBAction)onButtonClicked: (id)sender: { NSLog(@"Button Clicked."); }`

to SecondViewController.m file;

3. back to FirstViewController.xib file, I put an "Object" which I found it in Library,  to the xib file, and I set its custom class to "SecondViewController";
4. Then I tried to connect the button and the object, the object would show the IBAction method for let me choose it, and I choose it.
5. It seems no problem at all (maybe I can't find the error), but when I run the app and clicked
   the button, nothing happens.

I know there are other ways to pass the button event in such case, but I just want to know if this way works or is there anything wrong on it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Any object created in a XIB must be strongly referenced somewhere otherwise it will be released before you can do anything with it : create a strong IBOutlet for it in the first controller and connect that outlet to your SecondViewController in the XIB.